# python - elegantly handle sequence of multiple arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

Thus far I was handling multiple arguments via Optparse as a string,
Eg:

```
--update_entities="host_group hostname entity_type entities2monitor"
```

where entities2monitor has variable arguments, grabbing them inside the callback function via (notice the `[3:]`),

```
host = value.split()
(host_group, hostname, entity_type, entities2monitor) = (host[0], host[1], host[2], host[3:])
```

But how should I approach it when I need to feed parameters of the following form into a callback? 
(I have control over the SQL which will generate the Optparse input string)

- **action_name:** a space delimited string. (Eg: `'TEST ACTION'`)
- **hostgroup:** a string
- **actions_holder:** a list comprised by:

  - condition_type (string)
  - condition_operator (string)
  - condition_filter (space delimited string)

and

- **operations_holder:** a list comprised by:

  - operation_type: (string)
  - operation_sendto: (string)

Example:

```
--create_action='''TEST ACTION | client_service_platform | "CONDITION_TYPE_TRIGGER_NAME CONDITION_OPERATOR_LIKE Weighted Successful" "CONDITION_TYPE_HOST CONDITION_OPERATOR_EQUAL host01" | "OPERATION_TYPE_MESSAGE userid1" "OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid1" "OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid2"'''
```

This is what I have so far,

```
actions_splits = actions_parameters.split(" | ")
action_name = actions_splits[0]
hostgroup = actions_splits[1]
actions_holder = actions_splits[2].strip('"').split('" "')
operations_holder = actions_splits[3].strip('"').split('" "')
```

which kind of works but is there a more seamless way to get these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a namedtuple here:

```
import collections
Action = collections.namedtuple('Action', 'name hostgroup actions operations')
```

use `;` and `,` to differentiate your command components:

```
command= "TEST ACTION;client_service_platform;CONDITION_TYPE_TRIGGER_NAME CONDITION_OPERATOR_LIKE Weighted Successful,CONDITION_TYPE_HOST CONDITION_OPERATOR_EQUAL tt1scp1; OPERATION_TYPE_MESSAGE userid1,OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid1,OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid2"
```

now instantiate with:

```
a = Action(*command.split(';'))
```

which allows you to call:

```
a.name
a.hostgroup
a.actions.split(',')
a.operations.split(',')
```

of which the elements of last two can then be split again with just `.split()`

Comment: Truly welcomed discovery. Will fit quite nicely in the code. Have just finished reading the docs, mainly because I'm forced to use Python2.4 here I'll be using this recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/ for namedtuple implementation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to make this solution backwards-compatible! Valeu!

Comment: Hehe. I was this close to give you +1 for knowing Brasilian Portuguese :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it seems to me that you could use argparse and use the `nargs` argument to specify how many arguments should be consumed.

You probably know it already, but here's a link: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs

using `nargs=+` or `nargs=*` will put your arguments on a list. So with your example I think you could call your program like:

```
--create_action "TEST ACTION" client_service_platform \
  '"CONDITION_TYPE_TRIGGER_NAME CONDITION_OPERATOR_LIKE Weighted Successful"\
  "CONDITION_TYPE_HOST CONDITION_OPERATOR_EQUAL tt1scp1"'\
  '"OPERATION_TYPE_MESSAGE userid1" "OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid1"\
  "OPERATION_TYPE_EMAIL userid2"'
```

Comment: Thanks Fred.
I was aware of it but was trying to avoid installing it on this server.(it's an RHEL5 so using Python 2.4). Thanks for the explanation anyway